# Check if a browser plugin is blocked or unblocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, browser-plugin

ive done researching on how to determine whether a browser plugin is blocked / unblocked from the current browser in order to suggest user how to unblock required plugin before operating some website functions

My plugin is

> { "mime": "application/x-rbjnloguploader,version=2.7.200.8", "name": "RBlue Jeans Video Plugin", "description": "RBlue Jeans Video Plugin", "filename": "nprbjnplugin_2.7.200.8.dll" }

After doing research on some pages as follow

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Plugins/Site_Author_Guide_for_Click-To-Activate_Plugins
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins.plugins#Specification

Possibly, can it be able to detect crossing browsers?

Appreciate any help

Comment: doesn't really make sense. If your plugin is blocked, your plugin code won't run to tell user anything

Comment: Thanks for your comment, what i want to do is to check if plugin is  blocked by browser or not using javascript of jquery. I dont need plugin code to tell user. My plugin is a custom plugin, neither Java nor any other popular browser plugin like Flash or something. Here is the sample image of how plugin is blocked by Chrome browser http://cdn.ghacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/manage-plugin-blocking.jpg

Comment: OK, I've never looked at navigator.plugins object before. Now I understand it after playing with example in second link. WHat specifically are you having problems with? You can just check if `navigator.plugins['RBlue Jeans Video Plugin']` is defined

Comment: There is no explicit way to check whether a plugin is blocket or CTP. The site author guide should cover the usual use cases though, what are you missing?